# I am using Swift 3. I want to write my name in the text field & when I press the button, I want my name to appear on the TableView list

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift3

I am still a beginner at Swift… I am using XCode 8, Swift 3.0 (single view application)… I have a `UITableView`, a `UITextField`, and a `UIButton`.  I want to write my name in the `UITextField`, and when I tap the `UIButton`, I want my name to appear on the list of the `UITableView`.

Here is the code I wrote… Every time I write my name and press the `UIButton`, my name doesn't appear on the `UITableView`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource  {

    var list = ["Dina", "Sam", "Stremmel"]

    @IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!


    @IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!


    @IBAction func Addname(_ sender: Any)

    {

        if (input.text != "")

        {
            list.append(input.text!)



            input.text = ""


        }

    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

    {
        return (list.count)

    }


    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell


    {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]

        return (cell)


    }


     public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

    {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
        {
            list.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }


    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {

        reloadInputViews()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
@IBAction func Addname(_ sender: Any) {
    if (input.text != "") {
        list.append(input.text!)
        TableView.reloadData() // this line
        input.text = ""
    }
}
```